# How to add other fields for ModelAttribute in spring mvc controller

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-boot, modelattribute

I created a model for users in spring mvc and save data to the database using ModelAttribute...Data save successfully and I want to update some fields after save to the database... I use the ModelAttribute to update some data fields... When I click the update button the aspect fields successfully update and other fields change to the null... How can I store others fields in there stored values... I want to update password,mobile and email only..

this is my jsp.

```
<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: ignotus
  Date: 2/6/2017
  Time: 3:58 PM
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>User ${user.nic} </title>
        <jsp:include page="template/styles.jsp"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="bootstrapCssTest" class="hidden"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row headerRow1">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <jsp:include page="template/banner.jsp"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="authheader">
                    <%@include file="template/message.jsp" %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <jsp:include page="template/header.jsp"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-8">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="well lead">Account Details</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" >
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                        <p>Name - ${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}</p>
                                        <p>Agency - ${user.agency}</p>
                                        <p>NIC/Emp No - ${user.nic}</p>
                                        <p>VAT No - ${user.impoVat}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="user" commandName="user" class="form-horizontal" action="resetDetails">
                                    <form:input type="hidden" path="id" id="id"/>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="password">Password</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                                <form:input type="password" path="password" id="password" class="form-control input-sm" maxlength="15"/>
                                                <div class="has-error">
                                                    <form:errors path="password" class="help-inline"/>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="mobile">Mobile Phone No.</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                                <form:input type="number" path="mobile" id="mobile" class="form-control input-sm" maxlength="10"/>
                                                <div class="has-error">
                                                    <form:errors path="mobile" class="help-inline"/>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-lable" for="email">Email</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-7">
                                                <form:input type="text" path="email" id="email" class="form-control input-sm"/>
                                                <div class="has-error">
                                                    <form:errors path="email" class="help-inline"/>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form group row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="form-actions floatRight pull-right">
                                                        <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-success"/> or <a
                                                            href="<c:url value='./' />">Cancel</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form:form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <jsp:include page="template/footer.jsp"/>
        </div>
        <jsp:include page="template/stylesLoadHigh.jsp"/>
    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#emp").hide();
            $("#slsi").click(function () {
                $("#agency").val("SLSI");
                $("#emp").show();
                $("#nic").hide();
                $("#h1").hide();
                $("#agency").attr("readonly", "readonly");
            });
            $("#other").click(function () {
                $("#emp").hide();
                $("#nic").show();
                $("#h1").show();
                $("#agency").val("");
                $("#agency").removeAttr("readonly");
            });
            var dataString = $("#agency").val();
            if (dataString == 'SLSI') {
                $("#emp").show();
                $("#nic").hide();
            } else {
                $("#nic").show();
                $("#emp").hide();
            }
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var agN = $("#agency").val();
            if (agN == 'SLSI') {
                $("#agency").attr("readonly", "readonly");
                $("#h1").hide();
            }
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        function lettersOnly(input) {
            var regex = /[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/gi;
            input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        function lettersOnly(input) {
            var regex = /[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/gi;
            input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "");
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

This is my JSP retreive controller

```
    @RequestMapping(path = "/MyAccount", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String updateUser(Model model) {

            Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            long userId = 0;
            String agency = "";
            String units = "";
            List<String> roles;
            if (principal != null && principal instanceof AuthenticatedUser) {
                AuthenticatedUser auth = (AuthenticatedUser) principal;
                userId = auth.getUserId();
                agency = auth.getAgency();
                roles = auth.getUserRoles();
                model.addAttribute("user", userServices.getUserFromUserId(userId));
                model.addAttribute("roles", userServices.getAllRoles());
                model.addAttribute("units", userServices.getAllUnits());
                model.addAttribute("edit", true);
                return "passwordChange";
            } else {
                return "redirect:/login";
            }
        }
```

This is my update controller...

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/resetDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String reupdateUserDetails(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user,
            BindingResult result,
            HttpSession session) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "redirect:/somethingWentWorng/dataValidationError";
        }
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        long userId = 0;
        String agency = "";
        String units = "";
        List<String> roles;
        if (principal != null && principal instanceof AuthenticatedUser) {
            AuthenticatedUser auth = (AuthenticatedUser) principal;
            userId = auth.getUserId();
            agency = auth.getAgency();
            roles = auth.getUserRoles();

            User newUser=userServices.getUserFromUserId(userId);
            newUser.setId(newUser.getId());
            newUser.setUserUnits(newUser.getUserUnits());
            newUser.setUserRoles(newUser.getUserRoles());
            newUser.setAgency(newUser.getAgency());
            newUser.setFirstName(newUser.getFirstName());
            newUser.setLastName(newUser.getLastName());
            newUser.setImpoVat(newUser.getImpoVat());
            newUser.setUserName(newUser.getUserName());
            newUser.setNic(newUser.getNic());

            slsiLogger.info("Executing user update with user : [{}]", user);
            if (userServices.updateUserDetails(user)) {
                session.setAttribute(MESSAGE_KEY, "user update successful!");
            } else {
                session.setAttribute(MESSAGE_KEY, "user update was not successful");
            }
        }
        return USAER_MANAGE_REDIRECT;
    }
```

This is my model

```
package lk.slsi.domain;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String nic;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String mobile;
    private String email;
    private String status;

    private String agency;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String userName;

    private String password;

    private String impoVat;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "roleId")})
    private Set<Role> userRoles;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_units",
            joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "unitId")})
    private Set<Unit> userUnits;

    public Set<Unit> getUserUnits() {
        return userUnits;
    }

    public void setUserUnits(Set<Unit> userUnits) {
        this.userUnits = userUnits;
    }

    @PreRemove
    private void removeRolesFromUser() {
        this.setUserRoles(Collections.emptySet());
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

//    public String getSsoId() {
//        return ssoId;
//    }
//
//    public void setSsoId(String ssoId) {
//        this.ssoId = ssoId;
//    }
    public String getNic() {
        return nic;
    }

    public void setNic(String nic) {
        this.nic = nic;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getImpoVat() {
        return impoVat;
    }

    public void setImpoVat(String impoVat) {
        this.impoVat = impoVat;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getAgency() {
        return agency;
    }

    public void setAgency(String agency) {
        this.agency = agency;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        ShaPasswordEncoder encoder = new ShaPasswordEncoder(224);
        this.password = encoder.encodePassword(password, null);
    }

    public Set<Role> getUserRoles() {
        return userRoles;
    }

    public void setUserRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.userRoles = roles;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("User{");
        sb.append("id=").append(id);
        //sb.append(", ssoId='").append(ssoId).append('\'');
        sb.append(", nic='").append(nic).append('\'');
        sb.append(", firstName='").append(firstName).append('\'');
        sb.append(", lastName='").append(lastName).append('\'');
        sb.append(", mobile='").append(mobile).append('\'');
        sb.append(", email='").append(email).append('\'');
        sb.append(", status='").append(status).append('\'');
        sb.append(", agency='").append(agency).append('\'');
        sb.append(", userName='").append(userName).append('\'');
        sb.append(", userUnits='").append(userUnits).append('\'');
        sb.append(", userRoles=").append(userRoles);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

I want to store previous values in**nic,firstName,lastName,userUnits,userRoles** feilds and only replace password,mobile and email. **How can I do it from controller....** I don't want to pass data to jsp and retrive to the modelAttribute because security reasons.. I want to do it from controller.

Comment: Since you are saying it is update, that means your User object should have pre-filled values in JSP page. So i don't get this point, why some fields are empty/null. Ideally fields of User should not be empty/null

Comment: I can see you are not using form:label for firstName,lastName,agency and other fields, which is breaking spring binding....So it is coming as null on controller class, my suggestion is to use spring binding all fields of User

Comment: @Yogi thank you for your reply.